# Unable to pass hidden value to databse in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller

I want to pass in a the parameter name **"ID"** from my route to my database column **"created_by"** as i hit the submit button. I am using a hidden field in my form to perform this task. Can you please tell me where am i going wrong.

**Here Are My Routes:-**

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

**Here's My PostsController:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Post;
use App\user;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

public function create(Request $request)
    {
      return view('posts.CreatePost', compact('$request'));

    } 

  public function store(Request $request)
    {
post::create([
              'title'=>$request->title,
              'body'=>$request->body,
              'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'created_by'=>$request->created_by  ,
            ]);
return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);


}
}
```

**Here's My CreatePost View:-**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h2>{{ __('Info') }}</h2></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="/p">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Title') }}
                            </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="title"
                                name="title"
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"
                                 value="{{ old('title') }}" required autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                                @error('title')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="body" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Body') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="body"
                                name="body"
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control @error('body') is-invalid @enderror"
                                 value="{{ old('body') }}" required autocomplete="body" autofocus>

                                @error('body')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" id="created_by" name="created_by" value="{{$request->id}}"

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Submit') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Here's My Posts Migration:-**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->id();
          $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
          $table->string('title');
          $table->text('body');
          $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by');        
          $table->unsignedBigInteger('filled_by')->nullable();
          $table->timestamps();

          $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

**Here's a Picture Of DD:-**
[image]

It was passing the authenticated id to the filled_by column before i had added the hidden field and created_by column

i am just a beginner please help me it would really mean a lot

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you do is add an $id param to your create function like so

```
public function create($id)
{
      return view('posts.CreatePost', [
            'id' => $id,
        ]);

}
```

Then pass the id to the hidden field in your blade file like so

```
<input type="hidden" id="created_by" name="created_by" value="{{ $id}}"
```

your store method should work as is, provided you have an authorized logged in user Auth::user().

Comment: Tankss Buddy It Workeddd THAAANKS A LOTT

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To store the ID of the user that posted, I would do:

```php
post::create([
  'title'=>$request->title,
  'body'=>$request->body,
  'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
  'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->id,
  'created_by'=> Auth::user()->id,
]);
```

In this way, you don't need to pass `$request` in the create function.

I think that is what you want to accomplish...

Comment: i tried your way now i see a different error **"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_by' cannot be null "**

Comment: and i do have protected fillable in my Post Model

Comment: i tried with and without it still stuck with the same error

Comment: do you have any other way to perform this task

Comment: i cant use the auth user in "created_by column" the form is hosted by someone else and filled by someone else and the form is shared via url which will contain the host's ID (which will be stored in created_by column when filled)

Comment: if u have any other way to perform this task you are more than welcome